# How to add extra key value in django rest framework api view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

This is my models

```
class NumberList(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    spam = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.number)
```

This is my serializer class

```
class FindNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= NumberList
        fields = ('name','number')
```

This is my views

```
class FindName(ListAPIView):
    print("server error hai")
    serializer_class = FindNameSerializer
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        number = self.kwargs.get("number")
        queryset = NumberList.objects.filter(number=number)
        return queryset
```

which filter the number and return name and number on following url

```
path('find/<slug:number>/',FindName.as_view(), name='number'),
```

I am getting following result in my api

```
[
    {
        "name": "Saiful Hasan",
        "number": 8888888888
    }
]
```

However my target is also to return the total number of spam reported to the user in my API and final API should look like this

```
[
    {
        "name": "Saiful Hasan",
        "number": 8826478938
        "spam": 3
    }
]
```

Number of spam can be calculated as

```
spam=NumberList.objects.filter(spam=True).count()
```

How should add spam in result queryset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`SerializerMethodField()`--[DRF Doc]**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) here as,

```
class FindNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    spam = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_spam(self, instance):
        return NumberList.objects.filter(spam=True, number=self.context['view'].kwargs['number']).count()

    class Meta:
        model = NumberList
        fields = ('name', 'number', 'spam')
```

Comment: Hey It's filter out all the spam  but I want a filter for a specific number as NumberList.objects.filter(Q(spam=True) & Q(number=number)).count(). How to get a number here. I have tried using kwargs but could not help.

Comment: @imsaiful I've updated the answer. You can fetch the `view` object from `self.context` in serializer.